# Can I ask a question about a bash script I made

Tags: discussion

I have made a bash script to automate dirb and open the found directories in new tabs in firefox one by one, but it is does not work the way I want it to. Can I ask my problem in script over here ?

Comment: it looks like a programming/scripting problem, which you need to ask at StackOVerflow

Answer (score 2):

As schroeder points out in the comments, no - Stack Overflow (or maybe Super User) is better suited for that.